# How to install Kali Linux on a seperate partition on my second hard drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, kali-linux

I downloaded the 64bit Kali Linux distribution. I have an SSD which has Windows 8.1, and have a 1 TB HDD. I burned Kali Linux onto a DVD and when I put it inside my drive and try to boot from it, it says that I need to "reboot and select a proper boot device."

Is it possible to install Linux on a separate partition on a different hard drive that does not have windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your booting media because the system does not recognizing the boot-able media so kindly check either DVD drive or the DVD you burnt that they are working properly. And it is fairly possible to install any OS on separate drives. but I suggest to be careful while installing the boot-loader keep it on the same device otherwise it may cause not to detect the other OS it only boot the one either windows or the Linux.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the dvd drive, because the computer recognizes it, and I can see it in the bios. I think it's probably the dvd, so I might try burning the linux distribution on another disc and see how that goes. Also, when you say installing the boot-loader on the same device, do you mean installing it on the SSD with windows?

Comment: yes I mean that the boot-loader should be on the same device which previously installed boot-loader device in our case ssd. Because one incident was happen with me when I was maintaining a server and added an new HDD and installed the linux on that the linux was booting properly but the windows that was installed on previous hdd was not booting so my system admin head told me to keep boot loader on same device and it worked.

Comment: I fixed the problem, the image just didn't burn correctly onto the disk. Thank you!